# How to convert the Do N node from blueprint to C++ in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

[FirstPersonCharacterBlueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcg6a.png)

How can I convert the DoN node into C++ in Unreal Engine?
I attached an image of my BP for the Double Jump feature.

I try and test this BP for the Double Jump feature in my project, but my teacher asks me to do this feature in C++. I am pretty new to Unreal and done several types of research but still do not know how to convert this BP into C++. I would appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand what the node does? If yes, then translating this into code shouldn't be hard

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be a While loop with an increment in C++

```
int32 i = 0;
while(i <= 1)
{
    i++;
    // Do other stuff here.
}
```

You may want the increment to be a class member so it can be reset outside of the scope of the containing function.